# fatal error while using dns_get_record in php

Tags: php, networking, php-5.2

I need to get dns records, so i wanted to make use of php's dns_get_record function. By using
this i got a fatal error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function dns_get_record() in /home/guna/gstats/test.php**

I've php 5.2.5 installed and running on RHEL 5. pls check the code below:

```
$result = dns_get_record("php.net");
print_r($result);
```

So what could be the issue? Thanks!.

Comment: "i got a fatal error." Which one, specifically?

Comment: @George Fatal error: Call to undefined function dns_get_record() in /home/guna/gstats/test.php

Comment: @John This is what i got, Fatal error: Call to undefined function dns_get_record() in /home/guna/gstats/test.php

Comment: @Sekar: I would expect to see that error on PHP < 5 or on Windows less than version 5.3. Can you confirm that you are running on RHEL (Linux) and your PHP version is 5.2.5?

Comment: @George Yes, i echoed phpinfo and it says php version 5.2.5 and i'm sure am using RHEL

Comment: @Sekar: Please see my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the `disable_functions` setting in your php.ini file. This behavior may be present if `dns_get_record` has been disabled.

Alternately, if your PHP installation was custom compiled, you may wish to check the compile-time options to see if dns_get_record was removed. If this is the case, you will probably need to recompile and reinstall PHP.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts but, i'm not see any functions disabled. Here is the copy of that part:
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names.  This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
disable_functions =

Comment: I tried it posting the file in the server and it works, in server php 5.3. am using 5.2.5, I dont know what makes the php to throw this error in my system. Probably it should be os/php version issue. However , i'm going to accept your answer for your effort to resolve this issue. Thanks George.

Comment: @Sekar: I am very surprised to see this problem on the platform you described. I was unable to find any references to similar issues during my searching. Thank you for the check, but please feel free to discuss the issue further if new evidence comes to light.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP version < 5? This function is only implemented in 5.0 or greater.

Comment: i echoed phpinfo it says php version 5.2.5, should i need any tweak in php.ini to make it work?

Comment: George's answer is more suited to where you should investigate next.

Answer (score 0):

This function **is not** implemented in Windows (nor FreeBSD *AFAIK*.