# error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dns_get_record()

Tags: php

how to solved this. i got this error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dns_get_record()

[image]

where im using PHP 8.0
and using ARM Processing > with Oracle Linux VM Instance And use NGINX server installed version 1.21.4

the php i was try to test like this

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("php.net");
print_r($result);
?>
```

but get some error like message above.
So i need someone help for this.

for details here my phpinfo was included

```
PHP Version 8.0.16


System  Linux root 5.4.17-2136.304.4.5.el8uek.aarch64 #2 SMP Wed Mar 9 15:15:22 PST 2022 aarch64 
Build Date  Mar 22 2022 10:35:54 
Build System    Linux root 5.4.17-2136.304.4.5.el8uek.aarch64 #2 SMP Wed Mar 9 15:15:22 PST 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux 
Configure Command    './configure'  '--prefix=/www/server/php/80' '--with-config-file-path=/www/server/php/80/etc' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-user=www' '--with-fpm-group=www' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-iconv-dir' '--with-freetype' '--with-jpeg' '--with-zlib' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--with-curl' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-intl' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd' '--with-openssl' '--with-mhash' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-sockets' '--with-xmlrpc' '--enable-soap' '--with-gettext' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-opcache' '--with-sodium=/usr/local/libsodium' '--with-webp' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/onig/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/libsodium/lib/pkgconfig:' 
Server API  FPM/FastCGI 
Virtual Directory Support   disabled 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /www/server/php/80/etc 
Loaded Configuration File   /www/server/php/80/etc/php.ini 
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none) 
Additional .ini files parsed    (none) 
PHP API     20200930 
PHP Extension   20200930 
Zend Extension  420200930 
Zend Extension Build    API420200930,NTS 
PHP Extension Build     API20200930,NTS 
Debug Build     no 
Thread Safety   disabled 
Zend Signal Handling    enabled 
Zend Memory Manager     enabled 
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring 
IPv6 Support    enabled 
DTrace Support  disabled 
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, convert.*, consumed, dechunk


Zend logo
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v4.0.16, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support  enabled 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0

cgi-fcgi

php-fpm     active 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.discard_path    Off Off
cgi.fix_pathinfo    On  On
cgi.force_redirect  On  On
cgi.nph Off Off
cgi.redirect_status_env no value    no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers Off Off
fastcgi.error_header    no value    no value
fastcgi.logging On  On
fpm.config  no value    no value

Core

PHP Version     8.0.16 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset UTF-8   UTF-8
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   passthru,exec,system,chroot,chgrp,chown,shell_exec,popen,proc_open,pcntl_exec,ini_alter,ini_restore,dl,openlog,syslog,readlink,symlink,popepassthru,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,imap_open,apache_setenv  passthru,exec,system,chroot,chgrp,chown,shell_exec,popen,proc_open,pcntl_exec,ini_alter,ini_restore,dl,openlog,syslog,readlink,symlink,popepassthru,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,imap_open,apache_setenv
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 32759   32759
expose_php  Off Off
extension_dir   /www/server/php/80/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930 /www/server/php/80/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
file_uploads    On  On
hard_timeout    2   2
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:  .:
input_encoding  no value    no value
internal_encoding   no value    no value
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  300 300
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_encoding no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   50M 50M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 4096K   4096K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   Off Off
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision -1  -1
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
syslog.facility LOG_USER    LOG_USER
syslog.filter   no-ctrl no-ctrl
syslog.ident    php php
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 50M 50M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.assertions -1  -1
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.exception_ignore_args  On  On
zend.exception_string_param_max_len 0   0
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value
zend.signal_check   Off Off

ctype

ctype functions     enabled 

curl

cURL support    enabled 
cURL Information    7.61.1 
Age     4 
Features 
AsynchDNS   Yes 
CharConv    No 
Debug   No 
GSS-Negotiate   No 
IDN     Yes 
IPv6    Yes 
krb4    No 
Largefile   Yes 
libz    Yes 
NTLM    Yes 
NTLMWB  Yes 
SPNEGO  Yes 
SSL     Yes 
SSPI    No 
TLS-SRP     Yes 
HTTP2   Yes 
GSSAPI  Yes 
KERBEROS5   Yes 
UNIX_SOCKETS    Yes 
PSL     Yes 
HTTPS_PROXY     Yes 
MULTI_SSL   No 
BROTLI  Yes 
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp 
Host    aarch64-redhat-linux-gnu 
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.1.1k 
ZLib Version    1.2.11 
libSSH Version  libssh/0.9.4/openssl/zlib 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
curl.cainfo /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt    /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

date

date/time support   enabled 
timelib version     2020.03 
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2021.5 
Timezone Database   internal 
Default timezone    PRC 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.833333   90.833333
date.sunset_zenith  90.833333   90.833333
date.timezone   PRC PRC

dom

DOM/XML     enabled 
DOM/XML API Version     20031129 
libxml Version  2.9.7 
HTML Support    enabled 
XPath Support   enabled 
XPointer Support    enabled 
Schema Support  enabled 
RelaxNG Support     enabled 

filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp

FTP support     enabled 
FTPS support    enabled 

gd

GD Support  enabled 
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible) 
FreeType Support    enabled 
FreeType Linkage    with freetype 
FreeType Version    2.9.1 
GIF Read Support    enabled 
GIF Create Support  enabled 
JPEG Support    enabled 
libJPEG Version     6b 
PNG Support     enabled 
libPNG Version  1.6.34 
WBMP Support    enabled 
XBM Support     enabled 
WebP Support    enabled 
BMP Support     enabled 
TGA Read Support    enabled 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  1   1

gettext

GetText Support     enabled 

hash

hash support    enabled 
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b crc32c fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5  

MHASH support   Enabled 
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support 

iconv

iconv support   enabled 
iconv implementation    glibc 
iconv library version   2.28 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    no value    no value
iconv.internal_encoding no value    no value
iconv.output_encoding   no value    no value

intl

Internationalization support    enabled
ICU version     60.3 
ICU Data version    60.3 
ICU Unicode version     10.0 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
intl.default_locale no value    no value
intl.error_level    0   0
intl.use_exceptions Off Off

json

json support    enabled 

libxml

libXML support  active 
libXML Compiled Version     2.9.7 
libXML Loaded Version   20907 
libXML streams  enabled 

mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled 
Multibyte string engine     libmbfl 
HTTP input encoding translation     disabled 
libmbfl version     1.3.2 

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled 
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     6.9.6 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.http_input no value    no value
mbstring.http_output    no value    no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.regex_retry_limit  1000000 1000000
mbstring.regex_stack_limit  100000  100000
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 8.0.16 
Active Persistent Links     0 
Inactive Persistent Links   0 
Active Links    0 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   Off Off
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink Off Off

mysqlnd

mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 8.0.16 
Compression     supported 
core SSL    supported 
extended SSL    supported 
Command buffer size     4096 
Read buffer size    32768 
Read timeout    86400 
Collecting statistics   Yes 
Collecting memory statistics    No 
Tracing     n/a 
Loaded plugins  mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_caching_sha2_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password 
API Extensions  pdo_mysql,mysqli 

openssl

OpenSSL support     enabled 
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021 
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021 
Openssl default config  /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
openssl.cafile  /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt    /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
openssl.capath  no value    no value

pcntl

pcntl support   enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled 
PCRE Library Version    10.35 2020-05-09 
PCRE Unicode Version    13.0.0 
PCRE JIT Support    enabled 
PCRE JIT Target     ARM-64 64bit (little endian + unaligned) 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.jit    1   1
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     sqlite, mysql 

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 8.0.16 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.26.0 

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar API version    1.1.1 
Phar-based phar archives    enabled 
Tar-based phar archives     enabled 
ZIP-based phar archives     enabled 
gzip compression    enabled 
bzip2 compression   disabled (install ext/bz2) 
Native OpenSSL support  enabled 


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

posix

POSIX support   enabled 

Reflection

Reflection  enabled 

session

Session Support     enabled 
Registered save handlers    files user  
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary  

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly no value    no value
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_samesite no value    no value
session.cookie_secure   0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.sid_bits_per_character  5   5
session.sid_length  26  26
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies 1   1
session.use_only_cookies    1   1
session.use_strict_mode 0   0
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

shmop

shmop support   enabled 

SimpleXML

SimpleXML support   enabled 
Schema support  enabled 

soap

Soap Client     enabled 
Soap Server     enabled 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled On  On
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400

sockets

Sockets Support     enabled 

sodium

sodium support  enabled
libsodium headers version   1.0.18 
libsodium library version   1.0.18 

SPL

SPL support enabled
Interfaces  OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject 
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException 

sqlite3

SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite Library  3.26.0 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.defensive   On  On
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support     enabled 
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   On  On
assert.bail Off Off
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.exception    On  On
assert.warning  On  On
auto_detect_line_endings    Off Off
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
session.trans_sid_hosts no value    no value
session.trans_sid_tags  a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=    a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
unserialize_max_depth   4096    4096
url_rewriter.hosts  no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   form=   form=
user_agent  no value    no value

sysvsem

sysvsem support     enabled 

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support   enabled 

xml

XML Support     active 
XML Namespace Support   active 
libxml2 Version     2.9.7 

xmlreader

XMLReader   enabled 

xmlwriter

XMLWriter   enabled 

zip

Zip     enabled 
Zip version     1.19.5 
Libzip version  1.5.1 

zlib

ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib:// 
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate 
Compiled Version    1.2.11 
Linked Version  1.2.11 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable    Value
USER    www 
HOME    /home/www 

PHP Variables

Variable    Value
$_SERVER['USER']    www
$_SERVER['HOME']    /home/www
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] BT-Panel
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] 80
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] 127.0.0.1
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] 7800
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 127.0.0.1
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] HTTP/1.1
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']   /dev/shm/
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']    /phpinfo.php
$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']  0
$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] 200
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] BT-Panel
$_SERVER['GATEWAY_INTERFACE']   CGI/1.1
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] /phpinfo.php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] /phpinfo.php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  GET
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']    no value
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] /dev/shm//phpinfo.php
$_SERVER['FCGI_ROLE']   RESPONDER
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']    /phpinfo.php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']  1647919808.3467
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']    1647919808


PHP Credits

PHP Group
Thies C. Arntzen, Stig Bakken, Shane Caraveo, Andi Gutmans, Rasmus Lerdorf, Sam Ruby, Sascha Schumann, Zeev Suraski, Jim Winstead, Andrei Zmievski 

Language Design & Concept
Andi Gutmans, Rasmus Lerdorf, Zeev Suraski, Marcus Boerger 

PHP Authors
Contribution    Authors
Zend Scripting Language Engine  Andi Gutmans, Zeev Suraski, Stanislav Malyshev, Marcus Boerger, Dmitry Stogov, Xinchen Hui, Nikita Popov 
Extension Module API    Andi Gutmans, Zeev Suraski, Andrei Zmievski 
UNIX Build and Modularization   Stig Bakken, Sascha Schumann, Jani Taskinen, Peter Kokot 
Windows Support     Shane Caraveo, Zeev Suraski, Wez Furlong, Pierre-Alain Joye, Anatol Belski, Kalle Sommer Nielsen 
Server API (SAPI) Abstraction Layer     Andi Gutmans, Shane Caraveo, Zeev Suraski 
Streams Abstraction Layer   Wez Furlong, Sara Golemon 
PHP Data Objects Layer  Wez Furlong, Marcus Boerger, Sterling Hughes, George Schlossnagle, Ilia Alshanetsky 
Output Handler  Zeev Suraski, Thies C. Arntzen, Marcus Boerger, Michael Wallner 
Consistent 64 bit support   Anthony Ferrara, Anatol Belski 

SAPI Modules
Contribution    Authors
Apache 2.0 Handler  Ian Holsman, Justin Erenkrantz (based on Apache 2.0 Filter code) 
CGI / FastCGI   Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov 
CLI     Edin Kadribasic, Marcus Boerger, Johannes Schlueter, Moriyoshi Koizumi, Xinchen Hui 
Embed   Edin Kadribasic 
FastCGI Process Manager     Andrei Nigmatulin, dreamcat4, Antony Dovgal, Jerome Loyet 
litespeed   George Wang 
phpdbg  Felipe Pena, Joe Watkins, Bob Weinand 

Module Authors
Module  Authors
BC Math     Andi Gutmans 
Bzip2   Sterling Hughes 
Calendar    Shane Caraveo, Colin Viebrock, Hartmut Holzgraefe, Wez Furlong 
COM and .Net    Wez Furlong 
ctype   Hartmut Holzgraefe 
cURL    Sterling Hughes 
Date/Time Support   Derick Rethans 
DB-LIB (MS SQL, Sybase)     Wez Furlong, Frank M. Kromann, Adam Baratz 
DBA     Sascha Schumann, Marcus Boerger 
DOM     Christian Stocker, Rob Richards, Marcus Boerger 
enchant     Pierre-Alain Joye, Ilia Alshanetsky 
EXIF    Rasmus Lerdorf, Marcus Boerger 
FFI     Dmitry Stogov 
fileinfo    Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre Alain Joye, Scott MacVicar, Derick Rethans, Anatol Belski 
Firebird driver for PDO     Ard Biesheuvel 
FTP     Stefan Esser, Andrew Skalski 
GD imaging  Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Jim Winstead, Jouni Ahto, Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre-Alain Joye, Marcus Boerger, Mark Randall 
GetText     Alex Plotnick 
GNU GMP support     Stanislav Malyshev 
Iconv   Rui Hirokawa, Stig Bakken, Moriyoshi Koizumi 
IMAP    Rex Logan, Mark Musone, Brian Wang, Kaj-Michael Lang, Antoni Pamies Olive, Rasmus Lerdorf, Andrew Skalski, Chuck Hagenbuch, Daniel R Kalowsky 
Input Filter    Rasmus Lerdorf, Derick Rethans, Pierre-Alain Joye, Ilia Alshanetsky 
Internationalization    Ed Batutis, Vladimir Iordanov, Dmitry Lakhtyuk, Stanislav Malyshev, Vadim Savchuk, Kirti Velankar 
JSON    Jakub Zelenka, Omar Kilani, Scott MacVicar 
LDAP    Amitay Isaacs, Eric Warnke, Rasmus Lerdorf, Gerrit Thomson, Stig Venaas 
LIBXML  Christian Stocker, Rob Richards, Marcus Boerger, Wez Furlong, Shane Caraveo 
Multibyte String Functions  Tsukada Takuya, Rui Hirokawa 
MySQL driver for PDO    George Schlossnagle, Wez Furlong, Ilia Alshanetsky, Johannes Schlueter 
MySQLi  Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel 
MySQLnd     Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel, Georg Richter, Johannes Schlüter 
OCI8    Stig Bakken, Thies C. Arntzen, Andy Sautins, David Benson, Maxim Maletsky, Harald Radi, Antony Dovgal, Andi Gutmans, Wez Furlong, Christopher Jones, Oracle Corporation 
ODBC driver for PDO     Wez Furlong 
ODBC    Stig Bakken, Andreas Karajannis, Frank M. Kromann, Daniel R. Kalowsky 
Opcache     Andi Gutmans, Zeev Suraski, Stanislav Malyshev, Dmitry Stogov, Xinchen Hui 
OpenSSL     Stig Venaas, Wez Furlong, Sascha Kettler, Scott MacVicar, Eliot Lear 
Oracle (OCI) driver for PDO     Wez Furlong 
pcntl   Jason Greene, Arnaud Le Blanc 
Perl Compatible Regexps     Andrei Zmievski 
PHP Archive     Gregory Beaver, Marcus Boerger 
PHP Data Objects    Wez Furlong, Marcus Boerger, Sterling Hughes, George Schlossnagle, Ilia Alshanetsky 
PHP hash    Sara Golemon, Rasmus Lerdorf, Stefan Esser, Michael Wallner, Scott MacVicar 
Posix   Kristian Koehntopp 
PostgreSQL driver for PDO   Edin Kadribasic, Ilia Alshanetsky 
PostgreSQL  Jouni Ahto, Zeev Suraski, Yasuo Ohgaki, Chris Kings-Lynne 
Pspell  Vlad Krupin 
Readline    Thies C. Arntzen 
Reflection  Marcus Boerger, Timm Friebe, George Schlossnagle, Andrei Zmievski, Johannes Schlueter 
Sessions    Sascha Schumann, Andrei Zmievski 
Shared Memory Operations    Slava Poliakov, Ilia Alshanetsky 
SimpleXML   Sterling Hughes, Marcus Boerger, Rob Richards 
SNMP    Rasmus Lerdorf, Harrie Hazewinkel, Mike Jackson, Steven Lawrance, Johann Hanne, Boris Lytochkin 
SOAP    Brad Lafountain, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov 
Sockets     Chris Vandomelen, Sterling Hughes, Daniel Beulshausen, Jason Greene 
Sodium  Frank Denis 
SPL     Marcus Boerger, Etienne Kneuss 
SQLite 3.x driver for PDO   Wez Furlong 
SQLite3     Scott MacVicar, Ilia Alshanetsky, Brad Dewar 
System V Message based IPC  Wez Furlong 
System V Semaphores     Tom May 
System V Shared Memory  Christian Cartus 
tidy    John Coggeshall, Ilia Alshanetsky 
tokenizer   Andrei Zmievski, Johannes Schlueter 
XML     Stig Bakken, Thies C. Arntzen, Sterling Hughes 
XMLReader   Rob Richards 
XMLWriter   Rob Richards, Pierre-Alain Joye 
XSL     Christian Stocker, Rob Richards 
Zip     Pierre-Alain Joye, Remi Collet 
Zlib    Rasmus Lerdorf, Stefan Roehrich, Zeev Suraski, Jade Nicoletti, Michael Wallner 

PHP Documentation
Authors     Mehdi Achour, Friedhelm Betz, Antony Dovgal, Nuno Lopes, Hannes Magnusson, Philip Olson, Georg Richter, Damien Seguy, Jakub Vrana, Adam Harvey 
Editor  Peter Cowburn 
User Note Maintainers   Daniel P. Brown, Thiago Henrique Pojda 
Other Contributors  Previously active authors, editors and other contributors are listed in the manual. 

PHP Quality Assurance Team
Ilia Alshanetsky, Joerg Behrens, Antony Dovgal, Stefan Esser, Moriyoshi Koizumi, Magnus Maatta, Sebastian Nohn, Derick Rethans, Melvyn Sopacua, Pierre-Alain Joye, Dmitry Stogov, Felipe Pena, David Soria Parra, Stanislav Malyshev, Julien Pauli, Stephen Zarkos, Anatol Belski, Remi Collet, Ferenc Kovacs 

Websites and Infrastructure team
PHP Websites Team   Rasmus Lerdorf, Hannes Magnusson, Philip Olson, Lukas Kahwe Smith, Pierre-Alain Joye, Kalle Sommer Nielsen, Peter Cowburn, Adam Harvey, Ferenc Kovacs, Levi Morrison 
Event Maintainers   Damien Seguy, Daniel P. Brown 
Network Infrastructure  Daniel P. Brown 
Windows Infrastructure  Alex Schoenmaker
```

For `/usr/include/resolv.h` - here the my details :

[image]

[image]

for this just not found `dns_search` in that file location

and

For `php_config.h` for PHP 8.0 here details :

[image]

[image]

Hope have some answer for this situation.

Thanks

Comment: The only thing `dns_get_record()` requires is Bind but missing that shouldn't produce the error you're seeing

Comment: hm, how to fix that ? already reinstall php8.0 - still persist the same error

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521900/fatal-error-while-using-dns-get-record-in-php) help?

Comment: This function is not implemented in Windows (nor FreeBSD AFAIK)

Comment: - i was trying to search disable function but still no dns_get_record are disable, can view the disable function in my phpinfo above listed. ;
- hm im using oracle linux that call freeBSD where im using.

Comment: I'm using Windows and I can call this function on PHP 7.0 to 8.1. In OP's case, the answer from linked URL suggested to reinstall PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS functions in PHP require the following libc functions.

```
res_nsearch or res_search or dns_search
dn_expand
dn_skipname
```

Usually you can find all of them in `/usr/include/resolv.h`, or check with `man res_search`. If you can't find them, you need a new OS. (or upgrade libc-dev if possible)

You can also check your `main/php_config.h`, if the configure program has found them, you can find these macros like the following in the header file.

```
#define HAVE_DN_EXPAND 1
#define HAVE_DN_SKIPNAME 1
#define HAVE_RES_NSEARCH 1
...
```

If all these macros are not defined, check `config.log`.

Comment: i was search resolv.h so = `man res_search` - not found. hmm in oracle linux ARM processing how to upgrade libc-dev ? i still no clue for fix this `dns_get_record()`

Comment: You mean you can't either res_nsearch or res_search or dns_search? I think [res_nsearch](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36875/res-nsearch-3resolv.html) is include.

Comment: hi, sorry for this `res_nsearch or res_search, dn_expand, dn_skipname` i was found in that file location but for `dns_search` still not found at that file. so need to add `dns_search' for that ?

Comment: above, i was edit the question. can see at the file attachment image was been include for that

Comment: This is weird, can you run configure again? If HAVE_RES_NSEARCH is still not defined, you need to check the config.log, search `res_nsearch` and `__res_nsearch` in the file to see why it failed to find this function.

Comment: hi, when i shift to php 7.2 installed - it's work for dns_get_record(). But starting form php 7.3 - php 8.1 still same error can' fix that. this problem with Oracle Linux with ARM Processing ?

Comment: [The function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.3.0/ext/standard/dns.c#L786) doesn't depend on a specific architecture. [The detection script](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.34/ext/standard/config.m4#L342) doesn't seem to be changed from 7.2 to 7.3.

Comment: I found a difference: since php 7.3, it uses `AC_RUN_IFELSE` to detect system functions, so your problem may be due to the low version of autoconf (<2.50).

Comment: i see, how to check the version autoconf and want to upgrade that ? btw for these test i am using aapanel

Comment: `autoconf --version`, I'm not sure how to upgrade, it depends on the package manager you are using.

Comment: here the log autoconf = `autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later`

Comment: Have you checked `config.log`?

Comment: i don't found config.log - just found of this log = [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/24782017?key=83d10a1b5ad7ec71c64dd5691a3cdffb) **bold**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243383/discussion-between-shingo-and-m-zayn).

Comment: hi, i got reply form oracle here he message ;

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for reaching us on forum. You can refer [this doc](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html), and find that Oracle Linux 8 Supports, php:7.3

I would request your patience as we shall soon rollout php:8 as well, I shall take this as a feedback for our respective teams.

Thanks,

Comment: i think, need oracle linux still outdated for php option.

Comment: So they say php 7.3 is supported. May I ask how did you install php?

Comment: yes install via manager installer - use [AAPANEL](https://www.aapanel.com/)

Comment: I think I didn't make clear the situation, what I talked above is building php from source code. This is because `dns_get_record` is a builtin function, it's include in the binary while compile time. So you might wait for a new php build. If it's possible for you to build php from source, have a try.